# Iphone application run in background without backgrounder(Cydia)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, background, jailbreak, cydia

Is it possible to write application via cydia to run in background like appsyn? Work with jailbreak device.

Without Backgrounder(Cydia)

Or is it possible to hide icon form springboard and hide arrow(Corelocation)?

i want to run my app like run plist in background.

please help me
Thank(Advance)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, I originally wrote Backgrounder for exactly this purpose; to act as a model for others to use.

You must do two things:

1. Make certain that you app installs to /Applications/ (and not /var/mobile/Applications).
2. Create your own UIApplication subclass, and add the following method:

   - (void)applicationSuspend {}  // Do nothing

However, if you are targetting iOS 4.0 or newer, you should consider using one of Apple's provided multitasking methods.

Also, depending on what you are developing, it might be wiser to create a daemon (or daemon/client) instead.

Comment: how to install app to /Applications/

Comment: Currently my app derives from an NSOBject< UIApplicationDelegate, ... >.  What changes would I need to make to subclass UIApplication (I'm a c++ programmer so go easy on me ;).